# What is the result of a mysql SELECT query on a table already LOCKED (write) by another session?

Tags: mysql, locking

Everything is in the title...

If I use:

```
LOCK TABLE tableA WRITE
commands
UNLOCK TABLES
```

What happen if another session/user tries to make a SELECT query on this table?
I can't find it in the mysql documentation...

Will mysql respond with an error kind of "Error xxx this table is locked! retry later" or will mysql automatically wait until the table is unlocked? How long? Will mysql respond a timeout error if the table stay locked for a long time?

btw I also wonder if this case could happen:

```
LOCK TABLE tableA WRITE
```

and then php/mysql crashes

and so tableA stay LOCKED 'FOREVER' until mysql receive an UNLOCK TABLES command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just tested it with some PHP :

First point :

Let's use a script that:

- locks the table
- invoke another script that will try to do select on the same table 
  *(done in the same file with a switch on $argc)*

*foo.php:*

```
function showTableLocked( $link, $table )
{
    $query = mysqli_query( $link, "SHOW OPEN TABLES WHERE `Table` LIKE '$table'" );

    $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $query );

    echo "Is table locked ? :". (($data['In_use'] == '1' )? 'yes' : 'no' )."\n";
}



// Show table status
showTableLocked( $link, $table );

if ( $argc == 1 )
{
    // Lock the table
    mysqli_query( $link,  "LOCK TABLE $table WRITE" );

    // Check lock
    showTableLocked( $link, $table );

    echo "Call a concurrent script\n";
    echo "----------------\n";
    passthru( 'php '.__FILE__.' --no-recursion' );

    echo -"---------------\n";

}
else
{
    echo "Let's try to SELECT something\n";

    // Select something
    $query = mysqli_query( $link, "SELECT COUNT(*) AS foo FROM $table" );

    $data = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $query );

    echo "My SELECT result: ". $data['foo']."\n";

}


// Is table still locked ?    
showTableLocked( $link, $table );





// EOF
```

Execution outputs :

```
$ php foo.php 
Is table locked: no
Is table locked: yes
Call a concurrent script
----------------
Is table locked: yes
Let's try to SELECT something
```

And I have to stop the script since the second call is waiting for the lock to be removed.
So the SELECT is not possible.

For the second point :

*foo.php*

```
// include showTableLocked func def and init vars...
//

// Show table status
showTableLocked( $link, $table );

// Lock the table
mysqli_query( $link,  "LOCK TABLE $table WRITE" );

// Check lock
showTableLocked( $link, $table );

// Cal an undefined function to make PHP crash
GenerateSommeFatalError();
```

Notice that I did not UNLOCK the table nor closed the database connection.

First execution gives :

```
$ php foo.php 
Is table locked: no
Is table locked: yes
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function GenerateSommeFatalError() in foo.php on line xxx
```

Second execution gives the very same output, especialy the first test :

```
$ php foo.php
Is table locked: no
```

So it looks like table was automaticaly unlocked, I guess it is done when mysqli connection was automaticaly ended by PHP.

Comment: So the conclusion is that the `select` waits until the table is unlocked?

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez That is what it sounds like to me, but it is not very clearly stated even though that was the primary question being asked. I guess I will have to run my own test to get the answer...